# Integrating CMS 2.3 with Django 1.4

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-cms, django-sekizai

Hi I have got the following Error on runserver a simple CMS integration :

"""
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The 'js' and 'css' sekizai namespaces must be present in each template, - or a template it inherits from - defined in CMS_TEMPLATES. I can't find the namespaces in 'template_2.html'.
"""

I have followed --- http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html#sekizai-namespaces ---- this method

Can anyone suggest what went wrong .

I have added

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}  
<@html> 
<@head>   
 {% render_block "css" %}   
 <@/head>   
<@body>  
{% cms_toolbar %}      


 {% placeholder base_content %}   


{% block base_content %}

{% endblock %}



{% render_block "js" %}   



<@/body>
<@/html>
```

this to the base.html , but showing the above error .

Thanks.

Comment: Django version 1.4 and cms version 2.3

Comment: Have you added the sekizai template context processor?

Comment: yes   'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',

Answer (score 1):

Please provide settings.py configuration.

Try `pip freeze -r > requirements.txt` . Make sure that sekizai is in that list.

Comment: 'cms',
     'south',   
     'mptt',   
     'sekizai',   
     'menus', 'cms.plugins.text',
     'cms.plugins.snippet',
     'cms.plugins.picture',

Comment: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
)

Comment: Try `pip freeze -r > requirements.txt` . Make sure that `sekizai` is in that list.

Comment: Thanks Sekizai wasn't installed in the virtual env.